# AppCompatButton's height is different on devices?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm working with AppCompatButton and face with a problem. The height of button is different on some tested device.

For example:

on SamSung Galaxy Note 4:
[image]

on Nexus 6:

[image]
I defined my button as the following:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_to_cart"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:text="Add to cart"
        android:textAllCaps="false"/>
```

I don't know why my button are different between devices. Please help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Note 4 running on KitKat or Lollipop+?

Comment: My Note 4 running on Android 6.0 and my nexus running on Android 7.0

Comment: just a thought: I'd check if the app's theme or it's parents you use is something like @android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault . Sometimes this gives you different results on different devices.

Comment: @GeorgeTheodorakis I think this problem only on Samsung's device

Comment: ok, try to change your theme (or it's parents) to something like @android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to align button shadows (done by elevation). The default style for a Material button on some Samsung devices does not set the elevation or the stateListAnimator.
Try setting android:stateListAnimator for your button to sth like this:

```
<selector xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="translationZ"
                        android:duration="100"
                        android:valueTo="1dp"
                        android:valueType="floatType"/>
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
                        android:duration="0"
                        android:valueTo="2dp"
                        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    </set>
</item>
<!-- base state -->
<item android:state_enabled="true">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="translationZ"
                        android:duration="100"
                        android:valueTo="0"
                        android:startDelay="100"
                        android:valueType="floatType"
                        tools:targetApi="kitkat" />
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
                        android:duration="0"
                        android:valueTo="2dp"
                        android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
</item>
<item>
    <set>
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="translationZ"
                        android:duration="0"
                        android:valueTo="0"
                        android:valueType="floatType"/>
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
                        android:duration="0"
                        android:valueTo="0"
                        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    </set>
</item>
```

Comment: Do you still see the difference if you set the height to wrap_content? Also, what background are you using?

Comment: I changed the height of button to wrap_content then it look fine on Note 4 but the button on Nexus 6 is smaller than the edittext

Comment: What theme are you using? Do yoou have any default styles for the buttons in that theme?